# HTML5 audio time-tracker not working in Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on this HTML5 audio player that tracks the playtime of an audio file. I have gotten it to work on the page, but I cannot seem to make it work when it is called from a popover. I am seeing no errors.

```html
 <audio id="player"  ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);'>
      <source src="http://sifidesign.com/audio/explosion.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
      <script>
  
  document.getElementsByClassName("speaker").onclick = function() {updateTrackTime()};
  
   function updateTrackTime(track){
    var currTimeDiv = document.getElementById('currentTime');
    var durationDiv = document.getElementById('duration');
  
    var currTime = Math.floor(track.currentTime).toString(); 
    var duration = Math.floor(track.duration).toString();
  
    currTimeDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(currTime);
  
    if (isNaN(duration)){
      durationDiv.innerHTML = '00:00';
    } 
    else{
      durationDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(duration);
    }
  }
  
      </script>
  </audio>
  <div class="speaker"></div>
  <span id="currentTime">00:00</span> / <span id="duration">00:00</span>
```

What else could I try?

Thank you!
—T

Comment: what's your bootstrap version?

Comment: Boostrap version is 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Since the popover is created dynamically, you will have to use event delegation.

```
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  if(e.target.className == "speaker"){
    updateTrackTime();
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Full working code:

```js
 document.body.addEventListener("timeupdate",function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName == "AUDIO"){
      updateTrackTime(e.target);
    }
  },true)
  
   function updateTrackTime(track){
    var currTimeDiv = document.getElementById('currentTime');
    var durationDiv = document.getElementById('duration');
  
    var currTime = Math.floor(track.currentTime).toString(); 
    var duration = Math.floor(track.duration).toString();
  
    currTimeDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(currTime);
  
    if (isNaN(duration)){
      durationDiv.innerHTML = '00:00';
    } 
    else{
      durationDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(duration);
    }
  }
    
    function formatSecondsAsTime(secs, format) {
  var hr  = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
  var min = Math.floor((secs - (hr * 3600))/60);
  var sec = Math.floor(secs - (hr * 3600) -  (min * 60));

  if (min < 10){ 
    min = "0" + min; 
  }
  if (sec < 10){ 
    sec  = "0" + sec;
  }

  return min + ':' + sec;
}
```

```css
#currentTime,#duration{
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
  <audio id="player" autoplay>
      <source src="https://megafood.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Erin-Audio-Road-Less-Traveled.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  </audio>
  <div class="speaker"></div>
      <span id="currentTime">00:00</span> / <span id="duration">00:00</span>
```

EDIT

The script is working on your page because it's updating the time in the DOM:
[image]

The problem is that since you declared the HTML for the popover, it conflicts with the content that is dynamically-created by the popover because they have the same `id`. Since the popover content is at the bottom of the page, the script won't change it because there can only be one ID per page and it selects the first one.

I think the easy fix would be to change the IDs to classes for `#player, #currTime, #duration`

Comment: Could I be really obnoxious and please ask where this would go exactly? I have tried implementing it myself and I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @ThomasFredrikAverin replace `document.getElementByClassName("speaker").onclick = function(){updateTrackTime()};` with the code I provided.

Comment: I am getting this error:

[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'track.currentTime')
 updateTrackTime (Anonymous Script 1 (line 12))
 (anonymous function) (index.html:211)

Comment: @ThomasFredrikAverin which part of your code goes inside of the popover; the `audio` element, `.speaker`, `span`, or all of it?

Comment: @ThomasFredrikAverin I suggest you do more reading and playing around with HTML5 and Javascript because I know that you copied that code from another Stackoverflow answer. Read about `event delegation` and `event bubbling`.

Comment: Gotcha! I am usually not this deep in Javascript, but I will take some time to familiarize myself. Unfortunately it just still is not working from within the popup! It works outside on the bare page just fine, but the numbers just stay zeros the moment I call it from a popup.

Comment: @ThomasFredrikAverin send me your code with the popover so I can see it

Comment: @ThomasFredrikAverin it's working you just have to change a few things on your page. check my edit

Comment: Hmm... I tried to make the timer work outside the popup with classes and it breaks down when I swap the getElementById with getElementsByClass in the script. No errors, it just isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I mistyped. That is what I put. ByClassName